# python equivalent of matlab unidrnd()

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7

What is python equivalent of matlab unidrnd() function?

random.randint() may be an option; But I suspect, because for a similar code, I am getting different kind of behaviour in matlab and python. Is there any other function, I may be missing?

Answer (score 3):

I believe [`numpy.random.uniform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) is what you need:

> Draw samples from a uniform distribution.
>
> Samples are uniformly distributed over the half-open interval [low,
>   high) (includes low, but excludes high). In other words, any value
>   within the given interval is equally likely to be drawn by uniform.

Comment: Does numpy.random.uniform differ significantly from random.random or random.randint()?

Comment: Yes it does, in that it takes additional arguments similar to matlab's `unidrnd`. There is also the normal [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform).